# Should the 'alt' attribute on an HTML image describe the image, or the meaning of the image?

Tags: accessibility

I have a report with several sections. Many of these sections have a paragraph at the top that describes the purpose of the section, and these paragraphs are all styled with the 'i'-in-a-circle (information) icon at the top left of the paragraph.

For the 'alt' attribute of this image, should I use "Information icon", or "Report Section Description"?  I am more incline to go with the first, and maybe use something else directly on the paragraph to more explicitly describe it, maybe a title attribute or something.

Comment: Regarding the first suggestion: Instead of "Information icon" it should rather be "Information".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would go for a short tag that doesn't describe the image. As a screen reader user I prefer alt tags that are short and to the point. I don't really care what the icon looks like, what color it is, what it's shape is etc, all I care about is that this is an informational icon so what follows is not data. If you need more detail about an image use the long description attribute. For example if you were displaying a chart I would want an alt tag of "chart of the last 10 stock market days". The long description of the image could then be quite detailed, something like "On day one the market went up 200 points, on day two it went down by 100 points, on day three it fluctuated in a range of 300 points but closed about where it opened" etc.

Answer (score 2):

the Alt stands for alternative, so if someone say visually impaired were to browse a site using the reader, alternative would describe for them what they are missing visually.

Comment: So I should stick with my "Information Icon" which replaces what they would see, and it's up to them to infer that the paragraph following the information icon is informative and not actual data?

Comment: Yes, I would also provide an Alt tag for the paragraph in question.

Comment: how does one provide an Alt tag for a paragraph, and what is the point?

Comment: the same way as for any* (citation needed) html element <... alt="">. I just think it be good to have something like "The following paragraph provides information on...", to put things into context - don't forget, to us it might seem obvious that this piece of information is separate or relates to whatever, not so for someone visually impaired. If you have two <div>s, top and bottom, different info in each - depending on the layout of the html, the reader software might vocalize one after the other.

Comment: my XHTML 1.0 Transitional validation tells me that an 'alt' attribute is not valid on a 'paragraph' tag, so what tells me that screen readers will even recognise it?

Comment: I'd advise *against* putting an ALT on the paragraph itself: ALT is *alternative* text; if you put ALT on the paragraph, it would suggest you wanted that text read out *instead of* the paragraph's content.

Answer (score 1):

The alt tag should be descriptive enough to suggest what the image is if the image is not available when the user visits the page. I have seen image alt text such as "image" which means nothing but I have seen others with a long description "image to show the relationship between the game and quiz entities"

I personally would go with the longer more descriptive text

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this solution because the image is just a UI element which declares something about the paragraph.

http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/QY7ng/

CSS:

```
p{
    background-image: url('http://images.findicons.com/files/icons/2146/realistik_reloaded/128/error.png');
    background-position: top -128px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 128px;
}
```

you can use this pseudo class if it is only the first paragraph, otherwise work with a class
`:first-child`
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

**EDIT:** to answer the question. the `alt` attribute of an image should describe the image. But in this case you do not need an `<img ... />` tag since it is just to make it more clear for visible people that the paragraph contains meta info

Comment: +1 for the great idea @JP, but I would ideally like the image floated, so all lines in the paragraph aren't padded left 128px, only those to the right of the image. Also, how do I then tell screen readers that the paragraph is an 'info' paragraph?

Comment: @ProfK you can use a class to only add the image to certain paragraphs. http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/QY7ng/2/ I wouldn't know how a screenreader can tell that it is an info paragraph, but with the alt on the image it can only tell, this is an info icon in this paragraph. I wouldn't know a better way then this. Maybe you should use the `<blockquote>` element? http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/QY7ng/3/

Answer (score 0):

Alt icon is generally used when image is not displayed on the users screen. I don't get why you want to have it on paragraph. From a SEO perspective Information icon is more suitable.

Comment: I don't want an alt on the paragraph. I have an 'info' icon on fthe paragraph for sighted people, to indicate it is 'meta- information and not actual report data. I am asking about suitable text for the 'alt' attribute of my info icon.